# Implementing the Reader monad (from Real World Haskell book)

Tags: haskell, monads, reader-monad

```
newtype Reader e a = R { runReader :: e -> a }

instance Monad (Reader e) where 
  return a = R $ \_ -> a
  m >>= k  = R $ \r -> runReader (k (runReader m r)) r
```

I am having difficulty understanding these two snippets. I can tell that the first one is a record syntax description of a reader that has a function `runReader` from `e` to `a`, but the second one puzzles me.

By binding `m` with `k`, it's essentially trying to create a new `Reader`, but how does

```
runReader (k (runReader m r)) r
```

work out? I thought `runReader` only takes one argument, but it seems it's taking two right now, one being `k (runReader m r)` and another being `r`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am having difficulty understanding *the Reader Monad*.

***Edit:*** I should point to a number of resources on this, rather than attempt to repeat them.

- [*Monads for Functional Programming*](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf) by Philip Wadler. He calls them *state reader monads*.
- [*Chapter 22.1: Reader* in HaskellBook.com](http://haskellbook.com/) by Chris Allen and Julie Moronuki.
- [*Typeclassopedia: Monad Instances*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Instances_3) adapted from Brent Yorgey's [The Monad.Reader issue 13](https://wiki.haskell.org/wikiupload/8/85/TMR-Issue13.pdf).
- [LYAH chapter 13: *For a Few Monads More*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more).

> I thought `runReader` only takes one argument, but it seems it's taking two right now, one being `k (runReader m r)` and another being `r`.

If you look at the type signature for `runReader :: Reader e a -> e -> a`, this can be seen as either taking a `Reader e a` and producing an `e -> a`, or as taking a `Reader e a` and an `e` and producing an `a`. The point of the reader monad is to introduce an implicit argument.

> How does `runReader (k (runReader m r)) r` work out?

You could spell out the *bind* operator definition a little more:

```
instance Monad (Reader e) where 
  return a = R $ \_ -> a
  -- (>>=) :: Reader e a -> (a -> Reader e b) -> Reader e b
  ma >>= k = R $ \e -> let a = runReader ma e
                           mb = k a
                       in runReader mb e
```

That is, first "`ma` is run with `e`" (`runReader ma :: e -> a` is applied to `e`). This produces an `a`.

Then `k a` is run. This produces an `mb`.

Then "`mb` is run with `e`" (`runReader mb :: e -> b` is applied to `e`).

This is packaged up into `R $ \e -> ... runReader mb e`.

I've come to the thought that the difficult part of understanding this is mostly tied to the way *newtype* requires constant wrapping (`R`) and unwrapping (`runReader`) of its content, rather than the notorious *how monads work*.

---

Imagine the only monad you ever needed was the reader monad, and we could do without the `newtype` and `instance Monad (Reader e)` fluff. Then your definition could look like:

```
type Reader e a = e -> a
-- type Reader e a = (->) e a
-- type Reader e = (->) e

unit :: a -> Reader e a
--   :: a -> (e -> a)
unit a = \_e -> a
-- unit a _e = a
-- unit = const

ask :: Reader e e
--  :: e -> e
ask = \e -> e
-- ask e = e
-- ask = id

bind :: Reader e a -> (a -> Reader e b) -> Reader e b
--   :: (e -> a)   -> (a -> (e -> b))   -> (e -> b)
bind ma k = \e -> let a = ma e
                      mb = k a
                  in mb e
-- bind ma k e = let mb = k (ma e) in mb e
```

at which point it becomes more clear that all `unit` does is discard `e`, all `ask` does is return `e`, and what `bind` does is take two functions (`ma` and `k (ma e)`, aka `mb`) that both expect an `e`, composes them inside a new function that also expects an `e`, without having to explicitly pass `e` during the composition.

A misconception I had myself when learning how to write monad definitions was that `runReader` *runs* anything. It helped me conceptually to call it `unR` since all it does is remove the `R` wrapping.

Comment: This has been a very insightful answer! I will need the time to digest the materials though. You deserve more than my upvote!

Comment: I finally understand now.. I wasn't understanding record syntax properly. Thanks for sharing.